# Sistema de sites imobiliários e redirecionamento para cada dominio apontado

Tags: php, script, redirecionamento

Estou desenvolvimento um sistema imobiliário em que quando o usuário faz seu cadastro ele obtém uma URL básica para acessar seu site.

Exemplo: **foo.bar/modelo/1/site.php?id=73646**

Ou seja, todos os arquivos do sistema imobiliário estão dentro do diretório: *modelo/1/*

Porém, preciso que se ele optar em ter um domínio próprio, eu consiga redirecionar este endereço **foo.bar/modelo/1/site.php?id=73646** para o novo dominio apontando, mas para isso preciso colocar todos os arquivos do sistema neste novo diretório do dominio? Ou posso utilizar outra técnica? Imagina eu tendo 80 clientes utilizando o sistema imobiliário e se eu fizer uma atualização em um arquivo e ter que publicar em cada um dos 80 diretórios o novo arquivo atualizado, ou se eu precisar modificar a estrutura do Template?

Aguardo ajuda!

Comment: Mas eu preciso é de mascarar um endereço na url como faço? Apenas mascarar. Não necessariamente redirecionar.

Comment: Já melhorou bastante. Provavelmente no seu caso, é o contrário, você deve fazer o seu servidor atender o domínio do cliente. Assim, todos os 80 dominios cairão no seu site, mas pelo PHP você pode ler qual deles é, para saber como filtrar no DB.

Comment: Sim, mas quando passo o cursor do mouse sobre os links é visualizado o endereço do dominio principal do site de imóveis e não o endereço do site do cliente que o internauta está navegando. Com isso quando é indexado no google o site do cliente, aparece com o link do meu site que é o gerador de sites. Rsss. Como resolver?

Comment: Se você fizer os links tipo `href="/aluguel.php?imovel=7293866"` é sempre no dominio que você já está. se entrar pelo dominio do cliente, vai continuar no do cliente. Mas vai ser tudo o seu mesmo site, só muda o endereço.

Comment: eu mascaro o dominio utilizando FRAME.Neste caso do frame dá certo em parte, porque o endereço fica sempre estático www.novosite.com.br independente do link que eu clico. Quando o google faz a indexação mostra o estrago que é href="siteprincipal/aluguel.php?imovel=7293866 ou href="siteprincipal/aluguel-temporada.php?imovel=7293866 ou href="siteprincipal/venda.php?imovel=7293866. Sendo que siteprincipal é o site criador de sites. Rss

Comment: esqueça o frame, isso é só problema. Fazendo o mesmo site atender vários dominios, nao precisa de nenhum improviso. São os mesmos PHPs, mas os dominios totalmente independentes e funcionais.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33286/discussion-between-gladison-neuza-perosini-and-bacco).

Comment: Basta gerar um virtualhost, caso utilize Apache, para cada novo dominio que for criado. Claro que deve ter bom senso e saber os limites do hardware do servidor. Por exemplo, 100 websites num único server fica bem pesado dependendo do volume de dados. Vai precisar de um VPS ou um dedicado com boas espcificações de hardware.

Comment: Você está oferecendo uma recompensa em uma pergunta com resposta já aceita?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu pelo comentário no bônus, deve ser para a resposta aceita mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você conseguirá utilizar somente um diretório e realizar una alteração, mas nele você deverá verificar 2 coisas:

**Primeiramente** você terá de pegar a URL que o seu cliente utilizou para acessar o site e fazer as seguintes checagens:

**O cliente tem domínio, mas não tem direito de carrega-la?**

Nessa segunda etapa você deve pegar a URL que o cliente está tentando acessar, e neste caso você deve mostrar uma página de "não estamos funcionando ainda".

**Caso a URL tenha DNS e tenha pago. Como prosseguir?**

Neste caso a página responderá para seu servidor e seu servidor deve mostrar o site do cliente.

A dificuldade estará em como você poderá fazer esse check no Banco de Dados e o quão complicado está em fazer o site(apenas supondo) **id=73646** responder por **www.sitedocliente.com**. Mas tudo isso é uma configuração DNS que você terá de fazer em conjunto com seu **PHP e MySQL**.